# Push notification in xamarin android

Tags: xamarin.android

Could I send and receive notifications from mysql database without using fcm or azure, just by using sync or thread conception ?
And if I have to use fcm what i should do if I have no access to firebase  only by using vpn in my counrty.??

Many thanks
Abdalbasit

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can connect to your MySQL database without using FCM or Azure, but you cannot connect directly to the database from the phone. You would have to create your own WebService on the same server as your MySQL database. There's a lot of options on how to do this including using the popular [LAMP stack](https://www.wikihow.com/Build-a-LAMP-Server).

What does the WebService do? MySQL databases are only accessible locally on that server, so you need a web service (RESTful API) to allow external apps (web/mobile) to Create, Read, Update or Delete rows. (Read more about CRUD apis)

Since I am not an expert in VPN, and that part of the question is not specific to Xamarin, I would suggest searching/asking a question like "How to access Firebase through VPN ([like this](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/how-to/adding-a-tunnel)).